# Is it possible to CHANGE the position of a Marker in @react-google-maps/api?

Tags: google-maps, react-google-maps

I have an existing map that relies on using the `setPosition` function on a single instance of `Marker` in the v3 Google Maps API. I don't see an obvious way to invoke that function from the `Marker` component exported by `@react-google-maps/api`.

I want to use the `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` events to show a marker with (summary) information about whatever feature the user is mousing over in a live Google map. The existing javascript site works fine -- it uses the `loadGeoJson` method to add about 3,500 features to the map.

The documentation and examples show how to pass a `position` prop to the Marker instance in the `render` method, but that provides only a static marker location.

In my current `javascript` code, I do the following while handling an `onMouseOver` event:

```
function mouseInToRegion(e) {
  //...
  dataMarker.setLabel({'text': 'some informative string'});
  dataMarker.setPosition(e.latLng);
  dataMarker.setVisible(true);
}
```

In the above fragment, `dataMarker` is a reference to a single marker instance creating during map initialization (at load time).

Not surprisingly, the `onMouseOut` handler does little more than call `dataMarker.setVisible(false)`.

How do I accomplish the analogous behavior using `@react-google-maps/api`?

Comment: FWIW, I've been able to get this to work using what appears to be hack. When I render the containing GoogleMap instance, I pass the `center` prop as a state variable created with the `useState` hook (I pass in the initial value as a prop to the container).

I then capture a reference to the underlying API object using `useRef` and manipulate it as above. It seems to work. I'd still rather use the `Marker` component if that's an option, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the position of the Marker component of @react-google-maps/api by using use state to pass the value of your position in the `Marker's position parameter`. Changing the value of this will move the current marker instance to the new coordinate.

I created a sample code wherein I have place data from the json file. I first iterate and get each data putting each on a paragraph. Then everytime you hover on each paragraph, it will pass the data of the place. You will then use the data and change the state variables `markerposition` and `place`. It will then update the marker and infowindow to show the details of that specific place.

Here's a code snippet and the [sample working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/marker-changeposition-vouiy2?file=index.js):

```
/*global google*/
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

import { GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import data from "./data.json";

const defaultLocation = { lat: 40.712775, lng: -74.005973 };

class Map extends React.Component {
  state = {
    markerposition: defaultLocation,
    place: "Default Position - New York"
  };



  onMouseOverEvent = place => {
    this.setState({
      markerposition: { lat: place.lat, lng: place.lng },
      place: place.name
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMap
          center={defaultLocation}
          zoom={8}
          mapContainerStyle={{ height: "400px", width: "800px" }}
        >
          <Marker
            //onLoad={onLoad}
            position={this.state.markerposition}
          >
            <InfoWindow options={{ maxWidth: 100 }}>
              <span>{this.state.place}</span>
            </InfoWindow>
          </Marker>
        </GoogleMap>
        {data.map((place, index) => (
          <p key={index} onMouseOver={() => this.onMouseOverEvent(place)}>
            {place.name}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer. In the meantime, I elaborated the hack I described above into something similar.